# What in this world is she trying to say?

Tags: cipher, pattern, visual, grid-deduction

I happened to meet one of my friends after about a couple of years. Obviously we both were very happy, but still, she didn't leave her habit of challenging me to decipher what she was saying. I thought that again she'll give me some seemingly random characters to search for some meaning; but she didn't.

Instead she started drawing some boxes on the ground, which turned out to be two 5x5 grids, and yes there was a number in each cell too. This was what it looked like:

[image]

Obviously I couldn't decipher at that time what in this world she was trying to say, so I just clicked the photograph, and continued with the rest of our talks. And yes, she said that it is more of a visual puzzle.

All this happened some time back, but today I found that photo again, and as usual I didn't know what it meant.

What in this world was she trying to say?

<sub>By the way, this is a direct hint to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/80730/57435) puzzle.</sub>

Comment: Is the cell in the second grid (col 4, row 5) supposed to just show half of two?

Comment: @Elpharya It is supposed to show the complete "2". Thanks, I'll update the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She's saying

> "HI"

The puzzle is

> A Pair of Slitherlinks
>  [image]

Comment: +1, but note that the solution is far from unique, you can basically do whatever you like in the middle and then fill out the exterior accordingly.

Comment: That's the right answer! Maybe you should try the puzzle linked in the question? I think it'll be very easy now.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Are you sure? Slitherlink has specific rules - you have to form a single loop without crossings or branches. I tried the puzzle and there is only one solution. I'd like to see a counterexample if you have one. Unless you mean multiple solutions to the puzzle itself, assuming it's NOT slitherlink, then, of course, all bets are off...

Comment: @Amorydai I was not aware of the closed loop condition. Thanks.